# how to Read images from different directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

im looking for correct htaccess code to allow me to call images in my html file from

images_20170819/
images_20170820/
images_20170821/

however have it read them from

images/

thanks for any insight !

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/(.+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images_20170819/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^/?images/(.+)$ /images_20170819/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/(.+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images_20170820/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^/?images/(.+)$ /images_20170820/$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can check if the file exists for each image directories. For line 1 - line 3, if the request uri is starting with `/images/`, then check if the file requesting is inside the folder `images_20170819`, `%1` is rewritecond backreference to `(.+)`. If the file exists, rewrite the url internally to request the folder `/images_20170819/`. `$1` is the rewriterule backreference to `(.+)`.